# Regex to allow text, some special characters and keep below a specified length

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm trying to create a validation expression that checks the length of an input and allows text and punctuation marks (e.g. , ? ; : ! " £ $ % )

What I have come up with so far is `"^\s*(\w\s*){1,2046}\s*$"` but this won't allow any punctuation marks.  To be honest I'm pretty sketchy in this area so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
^[\w\s.,:;!?€¥£¢$-]{0,2048}$
```

`^` -- Beginning of string/line
`[]` -- A character class
`\w` -- A word character
`\s` -- A space character
`.,:;!?€¥£¢$-` -- Punctuation and special characters
`{}` -- Number of repeats (min,max)
`$` -- End of string/line

Comment: Thank you, this post is very helpful and explains it well.

Comment: Note that you might have to adjust this to the escaping rules in your system.

Comment: Also note that checking the string length before checking each character would be more efficient, but as far as I remember, validation in ASP.NET is done by a function that expects a single regex as parameter (which I regard as bad design).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
^\s*([\w,\?;:!"£$%]\s*){1,2046}$
```

Note that this doesn't limit the length of the input at all, it only limits the number of non-white-space characters.

To limit the length, you can use a positive lookahead that only matches a specific length range:

```
^(?=.{1,2046}$)\s*([\w,\?;:!"£$%]\s*)+$
```

(The upper limit on the number of non-white-space characters is pointless if it's the same as the length. The `+` is short for `{1,}`, requiring at least one non-white-space character.)

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know that.  How can I limit the length of the whole input?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to allow text and punctuation what are you looking to exclude? Digits? 
\D will give you everything that isn't a digit

Comment: That is a good point.  I do need digits too.  I guess I just need to make sure that there is no malicious code.

Comment: Haha, quick! try to define malicious code!  Maybe youre better off defining a certain type of code... if it is for html, just ban less than signs. That sort of thing.

Comment: Karl, defining a whitelist is generally more secure than a blacklist.  If you forget something in a whitelist, your users complain about not being able to enter sensible input, which is quickly fixed.  If you forget something in a blacklist, your users complain about your site being "pwned", which is not so quickly fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You may already know this, but: guarding against malicious input should be handled server side, not in form validation on the client side.  Black hats won't bat an eye at bypassing your script.

I think with most popular web front end frameworks there is library code for scrubbing input.  A short regex alone is fairly flimsy for guarding against a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression should match all your characters and limit the input:

```
^\s*([\w\s\?\;\:\!\"£\$%]{1,2046})\s*$
```

Comment: No, it allows infinite amounts of whitespace at the start and the end of the string.